Regarding Nyoka for converting models to PMML
I am debating whether to use nyoka or sklearn2pmml for converting xgboost model to pmml.If any one used nyoka package what their observations are?
I am trying to understand if any one leveraged nyoka package and how was your experience?

You should first try if Nyoka is able to convert your XGBoost model(s) at all. Nyoka has been unmaintained for years, so your question might get a definite answer already at that point.

I was able to convert xgboost model using nyoka but running into issues when using onehotencoder

Latest XGBoost versions have built-in categorical feature support, there is no need to one-hot encode anything. With Nyoka, you will be limited to legacy XGBoost versions and legacy XGBoost functionality. Maybe that's sufficient for your use case.
